# Python: need to get energies of charge pairs

Tags: python

I am new to python.  I have to make a program for a project that takes a PDB format file as input and returns a list of all the intra-chain and inter-chain charge pairs and their energies (using coulomb’s law assuming a dielectric constant of () of 40.0).  For simplicity, the charged residues for this program are just Arg (CZ), Lys (NZ), Asp (CG) and Glu (CD) with the charge bearing atoms for each indicated in parentheses.  The program should report any attractive or repulsive interactions within 8.0 Å.

Here is some additional information needed for the program.

```
Eij = energy of interaction between atoms i and j in kilocalories/mole (kcals/mol)
qi = charge for atom i (+1 for Lys or Arg, -1 for Glu or Asp)
rij = distance between atoms i and j in angstroms using the distance formula
```

The output should adhere to the following format:

```
First residue : Second residue  Distance           Energy
Lys 10 Chain A: ASP 46 Chain A D= 4.76 ang    E= -2.32 kcals/mol
```

(For some reason I can't organize the top two rows, but the first row should be labels and below it the corresponding values.)

I really have no idea how to tackle this problem, any and all help is greatly appreciated.  I hope this is the right place to ask.  Thank you in advance.

Using python 2.5

Comment: A better place to ask would be the psychic network ;-)  Please add details, code snippet etc. so that one can effectively help you.

Answer (score 2):

**Where exactly** is your problem? Your description is much too general.

The general idea is as follows:

- Load the PDB file and parse each line.
- That will give you a list of atoms and their (*x*, *y*, *z*) positions.
- Iterate over the list in a *nested* loop to compare each atom with each other.
- Compute the distance of the atom pair.
- If their distance is less than 8.0 Å, compute their charges.

Comment: Hi Konrad, 

Sorry if I wasn’t clear enough. Basically, I have to write a python code that is able to do the things you have just summarized. I then have to use this program on two files, one containing the oxy hemoglobin tetramer and the other containing the deoxy hemoglobin tetramer.  For each file, I have to generate files with the intra-chain and inter-chain interactions in the oxy/deoxy hemoglobin tetramers and analyze them myself.  My problem is that I do not know how to write this in python code.

Comment: @Two786: Ok, but have you even made an attempt at doing this stuff?

Comment: In all honesty, yes, I have been staring at the python GUI screen for a long time now and all I got was input = open("file.pdb",'r') and do not know what to do next.  I have been "googling" to see if I could find a similar problem somewhere as a guide to get this started as well but no luck.

Comment: In all honesty, if you are baffled at this early stage, FORGET ABOUT WRITING A PDB PARSER! At least for now. If you don't know how to drive a car, don't accept a job as a taxi driver.  DO get some training in driving, and then drive around a parking lot, and THEN you might consider giving a ride to a friend someplace. In Python terms, work through some Python tutorials to at least learn what a list is and a for loop and a dict.  Then Google for "Python PDB parser" - I found several decent options on the first page. Start with one of them, get some PDB data then follow Konrad's template.

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at solutions already done?

http://biopython.org/wiki/Biopython

http://pymmlib.sourceforge.net/

if you want to roll your own, you will have the implement databank format parser (which is trivial).
Then something like this assuming you structure is in atoms (I know this is not what you after, but perhaps this will give the idea how to do it):

```
for i in range(len(atoms)):
   for j in range(i):
        r = distance(i,j)
        if r < 8: Q += (atoms[i].q * atoms[j].q)/r
```

however, you have to be careful with hydrogens oftentimes they are not provided explicitly, especially with NMR data

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at the sites.  Perhaps, if someone can suggest a general structure of what the program should look like, it might help me to focus on it peice by peice.

Comment: @Two786 to start, try following, using input you got from open:
`for string in input: print string.split()`. somewhere I wrote parser long time ago, if I find it, I will post it.